# Bit Manipulation in Integer Array

Tags: c++, embedded, bit-manipulation, bit

```
  #define SET_BIT(byte, bit) (byte |= (1 << bit))
  #define CLEAR_BIT(byte,bit) (byte &= ~(1 << bit))
    uint8_t data [5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 7; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            if (some condition)          
        -->    CLEAR_BIT(data[i],j);
            else if (some condition)  
        -->    SET_BIT(data[i],j); 
        }
}
```

I want to understand how is bit manipulation taking place in arrowed lines?

When I declare *uint8_t data [5];*  does it mean...  An array of name data and I can store 5 uint8_t value(char basically) in it and in the location of each array index there will be 8 bits.[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7hU2.jpg)

Comment: Write down the data in bits and than follow the bitwise and, or, not. It's not that hard. With this `uint8_t data [5]` you are right. Be aware that the array isn't initialized. So there will be random data in it.

Comment: The array isn't relevant to the macros. But please note that macros like these is a horrible idea. You can vastly improve your code like this: `if (some condition) data[i] &= ~(1u << j); else if (some condition)  data[i] |= 1u << j;`. And now the code is suddenly readable to C programmers, where it was previously only readable by those who know your private, secret macro language.

Comment: Why arrays arent relevant to macros and why is it a horrible idea?

Comment: @Lundin - in C++ why not use `inline`?  readable and with type safety ```inline void SetBit(uint8_t& byte, uint8_t bitPosition){
   byte |= 1u << bitPosition;    
}``` @Kunal - for other people reading your code out of context, they can't know what `byte` means, it has no type.

Comment: @joepol Because you can't write code which is more readable than what I just posted. Macros and functions are just bloat and clutter in this case. C programmers are expected to know how to set and clear a bit. Would you write a macro `#IF_EQUAL(x,y) if(x == y)` ? No of course not, because that's an equally bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `define` the line `SET_BIT(data[i],j)` is being replaces during pre-processing with `data[i] |= (1 << j)` (consider using `inline` instead and have the benefit of type safety).

The best way to understand is to make an example of a simple case (avoid these nested loops).

(lets assume you're data array is initialized to 0, which is not currently the case)

for instance: `i = 2, j = 3`:

`1 << 3`  = `00001000` shift the value 1 three times to the left , `data[2]` = `00000000`

`|=` is a bit-wise operator, there for - a logical `OR` between each corresponding bits will take place and `data[2]` will be equal to `00001000`

now, for `i = 2, j = 6`:

`1 << 6`  = `01000000`, `data[2] = 00001000`

A bit-wise `OR` will take place and yield `1` for bits 3,6.

`data[2]` will be equal to `01001000`.

With this example you can understand the more complex example.

Comment: Okay, I got this thing

Comment: @Kunal great! if it answers your question you can [accept it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)